# Nano syntax highlighting working in nanorc files but nothing else

Tags: syntax, highlighting

I believe I fully understand the process of turning highlighting on for nano. However, it seems to work only in the `.nanorc` files themselves and no where else. I have tried uncommented all the coloring lines in:

```
/etc/nanorc
```

and created a `.nanorc` file in root and copied all the lines to that.

Still only working for `.nanorc` files. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, that only took me a lifetime. The files I was trying to get nano working for were .cgi and .js extensions. Well, those extensions were not listed in the actual nano syntax coloring files themselves. So They were being included when I uncommented them or inserted them into a .nanorc file, however the files I was attempting to edit were not included to be colored. Once I changed the individual include files adding the correct extensions for my situation, everything works like a charm.